# How to redraw specific rectangle of control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, controls, paint

From the logic of my program I know I need to redraw the rectangle between `top_left = {x=32,y=32}` and `bottom_right = {x=64,y=64}` of a simple WinForms `Control`. I don't want to redraw <strike>the whole client area</strike> but only a part of it (performance reasons). WinApi can't tell what part must be redrawn, I must tell it. So how can I do that ?

The rectangle to redraw is different every time I need this feature.

I thought:

- send `WM_PAINT` message (but I can't figure out how to transmit the rectangle, since wParam and lParam are always 0 when this message usually arrives)
- ...

*(Hope this is not duplicate. I'll remove if it is.)*

Comment: Why don't you use different control for different region?

Comment: @Muctadir Because the region to redraw is dynamic. It's different every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Invalidate` method that accepts rectangle.

```
control.Invalidate(new Rectangle(32, 32, 32, 32));
control.Update(); //to invalidate control immediately
```

it invalidates specific region of control which will be repainted at the next paint operation.

Comment: Note: Invalidate does guarente to be called immediatly.

Comment: @Pengu true, adding `control.Update()` fixes this

Comment: @Pengu Was that a typo ("does" although meant "doesn't") ? Because this conversation perplexes me.

Comment: Yes,  a typo - sorry :) From Msdn: **Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the Invalidate method.** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dtk06x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx